# How to get the pointer to MFC document class in a single SDI MFC app built as DLL, export.cpp setup standard call to function?

Tags: pointers, dll, mfc, export

I have an MFC program in VS2005 dynamic link library, single SDI, app name c2view, document class c2viewDoc, view class c2viewView. This is a  4 component model, single doc interface.

Inside the dynamic link library  is a function defined in export h  and export.cpp as stand  call  ( a , b) I do have access to the main window pointer;

But, I need the pointer to the document class Cc2viewDoc, so that I can use the calling parameters a and b to update member variables in the document class !!
Page 503 of Jeff Prosise imples that m_pDocument is a member variable of the Cc2viewView class, so, I suppose, if you can get me the pointer to the Cc2viewView class, cvwcp*,  I could try to proceed with cvwcp->m_pDocument.

After many weeks of struggle I did get the MFC c2view.dll to call from c# and do a drawing. Now the next step is to pass the called parameters on the argument list of Shograph int a and int b to update members in the Cc2viewDoc.

Please help me.

I tried to get the pointer to the C Document class from C Win App or c2viewApp  as  A f x g e t A p p ( )

nothing works.
I am in export.cpp

- I n t _ s t d call  s h o g r a p h ( a , b)
  and need the pointer to the doc class so I can update its members based on a and b

Answer (score 2):

You should not expose internals of your DLL to the outside world, for many reasons.

Primarily - no one should care if your DLL implements MFC Document/View architecture. As important - it is simply not safe, as there is potential for a version conflict, object lifetime management, etc.

The best practice, I believe, is to create a simple "extern C" API for your required functionality and call it from whwtever client you have.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can you  post a reference to creating an extern C API that would allow the parameters a, and b in  function shograph(a,b) to enter the OnDraw function of a CView  such as pDC->LineTo(a,b);

Comment: @billg You can see an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp?view=msvc-170  In your DLL, I would have a global variable pointing to your CView, and just delegate the external call to that view.